# Can CRM 4.0 and Exchange server be installed on different domains but still work together?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, microsoft-dynamics-crm, crm

Is it possible to install CRM 4.0 server and an Exchange server on two separate domains but still have them work together?

Comment: CRM is a generic software category, not a product name.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume gwc is talking about MS CRM, since everything else mentioned is Microsoft-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, but it can get very messy, very fast and you loose a lot of the integration that would otherwise be very easy to set up.

I know of a client that did this on two separate domains using federation, however it was very messy and I would not recommend doing it.

... That being said, if you are talking about two separate domains in the same forest, it may be a lot easier.